# Python Script for Running Hackerrank tests locally

Tags: python, testing

I found [this script](https://gist.github.com/zodman/d8d3ede4b1f1e050caaf890424d04ee8) for running Hackerrank tests locally. According to the instructions, I should "Just run it in the sample test cases folder that you downloaded from hackerrank."

I have not yet been able to get it to work. I'm not sure what arguments I should pass, and also whether I should unzip the test files first (the code uses `rb` mode so maybe the zipped ones?)

Can anyone please provide more detail about how to get this working?

```
# to use with a python3 tested on windows
import subprocess
import sys
cmd = [
    'python',
    sys.argv[1]
]
process = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

input = open(sys.argv[2], "rb").read()
out_file = open(sys.argv[3], "rb").read()
out, err = process.communicate(input)

if err:
    print(err.decode("utf-8"))

out = out[:-1]
if out == out_file:
    print("WIN")
print(out.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: When you say you haven't been able to get it to work, what exactly didn't work? Did you get an error? What was the error? What command did you use to run this script?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://gist.github.com/zodman/d8d3ede4b1f1e050caaf890424d04ee8) seems like a revised version to run this, albeit not clear on the instructions as to how to do this. My guess is that the file `runpy3.py` should be passed the parameters for the filename, input, and output file, and you have to unzip it to enable a binary read command.

An easy way to run this would be to use the first version of this script [here](https://gist.github.com/miratcan/429895ef7c78a2c00cb7de9a44b11e6b). To run this (and as stated), you simply have to be present in the sample test cases folder and run it in there.

Based on these

```
INPUT_FOLDER = 'input/'
OUTPUT_FOLDER = 'output/'
SOLUTION_FILE = 'solution.py'
```

You should be in the root of the test cases folder to run this, i.e. the parent folder of the `INPUT_FOLDER` or `OUTPUT_FOLDER`.

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comments, you can run the Python2 code with Python3 by making the necessary changes and this should work flawlessly. For Python3 solution, you need to run the program passing in the required argument vectors. If my understanding is correct it should be `python runpy3.py <InputFile> <OutputFile>`, and here you can see that `argv[1-3]` corresponds to the required filenames that is required to run it, i.e. referring to the following

```
SOLUTION_FILE = 'solution.py'
INPUT_FOLDER = 'input/'
OUTPUT_FOLDER = 'output/'
```

Comment: That's Python 2 though, isn't it?

Comment: Sadly not. Firstly there are the print statements, but there is more. I ran `python -m lib2to3` on it but then got `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` when I ran it.

Comment: @RobinAndrews Other than the print statements I don't see any changes that need to be made;  you simply have to encapsulate them in brackets and it should work. If errors do show up then you can simply search the error and fix it. I may have also figured out the solution on how to run this with python 3 - see the updated answer.